# How to set body field display programmatically on node type install?

Tags: 7, entities, installation

When hook_installing a new custom node type filled with custom fields I call `field_create_instance($instance)` where I also set the custom fields' display like so:

```
'display' => array(
  'default' => array( // view mode
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'text_default'
  ),
  'teaser' => array( // view mode
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'hidden'
  )
)
```

I also added a body field via `node_add_body_field($type)` but where can I set that body's display properties programmatically? Per default it's set to be displayed in the teaser view. I want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access and alter the view mode configuration via [field_bundle_settings()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_bundle_settings/7), (which is basically a shortcut to `variable_get` and `variable_set`):

```
$bundle = 'my_node_type';
$bundle_settings = field_bundle_settings('node', $bundle);
$bundle_settings['view_modes']['teaser']['custom_settings'] = true;
field_bundle_settings('node', $bundle, $bundle_settings);
```

Comment: Is it possible this doesn't work for Drupal's body field?

Comment: `Body` is a field just like any other (you can even remove it). A common problem during installation are stale caches. Try to run your steps over multiple processes/requests first.